# typescript-uncaught referenceError: require is not defined

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, enums

Visual Studio 2015 update 3.
I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

on:

```
import { Category } from "./Enums"; at runtime.
```

[image: Solution-app.ts-Enums.ts-Interface.ts-tsconfig.ts pictures]

I don't really understand why I am getting this error (I am quite new to Typescript )

enums.ts:

```
export enum Category { Biography, Poetry, Fiction, History, Children }
```

interface.ts:

```
import { Category } from './enums';
export interface Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    available: boolean;
    category: Category;
    pages?: number;
    markDamaged?: DamageLogger;
}
```

app.ts:

```
import { Category } from './enums';
import { Book, DamageLogger, Author, Librarian } from './interfaces';
import { UniversityLibrarian } from './classes';

function GetAllBooks(): Book[] {

    let books = [
        { id: 1, title: 'Ulysses', author: 'James Joyce', available: true, category: Category.Fiction },
        { id: 2, title: 'A Farewell to Arms', author: 'Ernest Hemingway', available: false, category: Category.Fiction },
        { id: 3, title: 'I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings', author: 'Maya Angelou', available: true, category: Category.Poetry },
        { id: 4, title: 'Moby Dick', author: 'Herman Melville', available: true, category: Category.Fiction }
    ];

    return books
```

;

Comment: Please replace that collection of screenshots with actual text. Screenshots of text are useless.

Comment: I add source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this error by using "outFile" in tsconfig.json.
If we used "outFile" we shouldn't use "module": "commonjs", we should use just "amd" and "system"

Comment: Would've been nice if you could actually provide us with some code. The question and answer both are very vague

Answer (score 1):

You need to install types for node

```
npm i -D @types/node
```

The [`require` definition is in there](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/index.d.ts#L73)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bruno.  I've installed it but still does not work properly...